# T-SQL OVER/PARTITION BY query with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I am struggling with a SQL query and while I have looked at many similar answers none of them quite fit my situation.  I have a dataset as below:

```
Date1       Amount 1    Index   Date2               Type Supplier
31/03/2018  410000.00   17      16/04/2018 06:27    102  A
31/03/2018  410000.00   17      16/04/2018 06:31    102  B
31/03/2018  400000.00   2       16/04/2018 06:37    102  A
31/03/2018  400000.00   2       16/04/2018 06:38    102  B
30/06/2018  0           20      04/07/2018 08:23    202  A
30/06/2018  0           20      04/07/2018 08:23    202  B
30/06/2018  412000.00   20      06/07/2018 12:46    102  A
30/06/2018  412000.00   20      06/07/2018 12:47    102  B
30/06/2018  442000.00   100     16/07/2018 06:27    102  A
30/06/2018  442000.00   100     16/07/2018 06:31    102  B
```

For each Date1 where there are multiple rows with the same Type, I only want the rows where the index matches the index of the maximum Date2 so I want this output:

```
Date1       Amount 1    Index   Date2               Type Supplier
31/03/2018  400000.00   2       16/04/2018 06:37    102  A
31/03/2018  400000.00   2       16/04/2018 06:38    102  B
30/06/2018  0           20      04/07/2018 08:23    202  A
30/06/2018  0           20      04/07/2018 08:23    202  B
30/06/2018  442000.00   100     16/07/2018 06:27    102  A
30/06/2018  442000.00   100     16/07/2018 06:31    102  B
```

I feel it should be possible with some form of conditional MAX() OVER (PARTITION BY) but for the life of me I can't work out how to do it.

Comment: not able to understand ur output .. for date 31/03/2018, there are multiple rows in your data which have different INDEX values .. but ur output does not show every index value

Comment: That is exactly the point - I want to exclude rows where the index value does not match the index of the max Date2 for that Date1 column.  I have amended the March numbers to make it clearer.

Comment: there is only one INDEX column in ur data .. what is the index value of DATE2 ?

Comment: can you tell why first two rows are excluded? just for an example to understand logic for the output

Comment: For date 31/03 and Type 102, the row with the highest date2 has index 2. Therefor any rows with that date and type where the index is not 2 are excluded. Correct?

Comment: The index column is independent of the date columns.  Basically the users can enter a value for a date (Date1) and must assign it an Index.  This process generates two rows in the DB.  This is timestamped in Date2.  They can come back later and change the value, but must assign it a new Index so we have a multiple rowsets for the same Date1 with different timestamps (Date2). we want the latest set entered which can be identified by the Index associated with the latest change (max Date2)

Comment: For some insane reason the index is picked by the user without any rules - it can go up or down but has to be lower than 150...  I didn't design the entry system!!

Answer (score 2):

Use [LAST_VALUE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) analytic function together with a subquery.
The below working example is for Oracle (I prefer Oracle because I always have a problem with converting dates on SQLServer), but the idea of the query is the same, the syntax also is the same:
Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/004ce7/19

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT t.* ,
     last_value( "INDEX" ) OVER 
        ( partition by date1, "TYPE" order by date2
          ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) xx
   FROM table1 t
) x
WHERE xx = "INDEX"
ORDER BY date1;
```

---

```
|                DATE1 | AMOUNT1 | INDEX |                 DATE2 | TYPE | SUPPLIER |  XX |
|----------------------|---------|-------|-----------------------|------|----------|-----|
| 2018-03-31T00:00:00Z |  400000 |     2 | 2018-04-16 06:37:00.0 |  102 |        A |   2 |
| 2018-03-31T00:00:00Z |  400000 |     2 | 2018-04-16 06:38:00.0 |  102 |        B |   2 |
| 2018-06-30T00:00:00Z |  442000 |   100 | 2018-07-16 06:27:00.0 |  102 |        A | 100 |
| 2018-06-30T00:00:00Z |  442000 |   100 | 2018-07-16 06:31:00.0 |  102 |        B | 100 |
| 2018-06-30T00:00:00Z |       0 |    20 | 2018-07-04 08:23:00.0 |  202 |        B |  20 |
| 2018-06-30T00:00:00Z |       0 |    20 | 2018-07-04 08:23:00.0 |  202 |        A |  20 |
```

Comment: I like the concise nature of this one, but unfortunately I am on SQL Server 2008 and LAST_VALUE hasn't got there yet :(

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want. Note the use of `ROW_NUMBER` as opposed to `RANK` - `RANK` will produce multiple values of 1 where `Date2` is the same, `ROW_NUMBER` will produce unique incremental values for `rn`:

```
SELECT
    [Date1],
    [Amount 1],
    [Index],
    [Date2],
    [Type],
    [Supplier]
FROM my_table
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        [Index],
        [Type],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Date1], [Type] ORDER BY [Date2] DESC) AS rn
    FROM my_table
) AS subquery
    ON subquery.rn = 1
    AND subquery.[Index] = my_table.[Index]
    AND subquery.[Type] = my_table.[Type]
```

Comment: I can see what you are doing here, but I can't get it to work in my environment - the dataset isn't quite as simple as I showed in my question.

Comment: @DomG apologies, I didn't see the stipulation being the set (`Date1`, `Type`). I've fixed it up, should be good now

Answer (score 1):

Use row_number()

```
SELECT [Date1],[Amount 1],[Index],[Date2],[Type],[Supplier]
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Date1] ORDER BY [Date2] DESC) AS rn
    FROM tablename
) a
WHERE a.rn in( 1,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        *,
        MxDt =ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Date1,[Type] ORDER BY Date2 DESC)
        FROM YourTableName
)
SELECT
    *
    FROM CTE C1
        WHERE EXISTS
        (
            SELECT
                1
                FROM CTE C2
                    WHERE [Index] = C1.[Index]
                        AND [Type]= C1.[Type]
                        AND C2.MxDt =1
        )
```

Comment: Whilst not as clean as I would like it to be this one does work for me, thank you very much.

Comment: On further investigation it fails when there are multiple Date1 instances in the system. :(

Answer (score 0):

The subquery sorts your data so that the row that controls the index is always row_no one for each grouping of date and type. The outer query returns all rows that have the same date1, type, index combo, but ignores the others

```
Select *
From Data D
    inner join SortedData S on S.Date1 = A.Date1 
          and S.Type = A.Type 
          and S.RowNo = 1 
          and D.Index = A.index

(Select Date1, Type, Index, row_Number() over (Partition by Date1, Type ORDER BY Date2 DESC) as RowNo From Data) SortedData
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated subquery :

```
select t.*
from table t
where Index = (select top (1) t1.Index
               from table t1
               where t1.Date1 = t.Date1 and t1.type = t.type
               order by t1.date2 desc
              );
```